# How can I minify or at least make my code more readable without losing on performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've finished programming an exploding skateboard model which is on my website: https://website.stckd.space/skateboards. However, I think my code is really messy and I don't know how to make it better without losing performance. Is there for instance any way to declare all ref objects at once?.

I know this is a bit of a broad question and therefore there maybe isn't one true answer, but if you have any input on making this code better, please let me know.

**The code:**

```
import React, { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { OrbitControls, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Color, MeshLambertMaterial, MeshStandardMaterial } from "three";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../theme/theme";
import { GLTF } from "three-stdlib";
import * as THREE from "three";

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Circle002_1: THREE.Mesh;
    Circle002_2: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder_1: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder_2: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder001: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder002: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder013: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder013_1: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder004: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder005: THREE.Mesh;
  };
  materials: {
    grip_layer: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    skateboard_wood: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    wheel_connector: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    screw: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    wheels: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
  };
};

export default function Model({ ...props }: JSX.IntrinsicElements["group"]) {
  //* import theme colors
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
 

  // *declare 3d object resources
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/skateboard.gltf") as GLTFResult;
  const wired = new MeshStandardMaterial();
  var themeColor = theme.cta;
  wired.wireframe = true;
  wired.color.set(themeColor);
  

  //* declare all 3d object refs
  const group = useRef<any>();
  const orbitRef = useRef<any>();
  const lwheel = useRef<any>();
  const rwheel = useRef<any>();
  const lbwheel = useRef<any>();
  const rbwheel = useRef<any>();
  const bgroup = useRef<any>();
  const fgroup = useRef<any>();
  const grip = useRef<any>();
  const btruck = useRef<any>();
  const ftruck = useRef<any>();
 
  var mouseX: number = 0;
  var mouseY: number = 0;

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    mouseX = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) / window.innerWidth;
    mouseY = (e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2) / window.innerHeight;
  });

  useFrame(() => {
    lwheel.current.position.y = -1 - window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    lwheel.current.rotation.y -= 0.01;
    rwheel.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
    lbwheel.current.rotation.y += 0.01;
    rbwheel.current.rotation.y -= 0.01;
    rwheel.current.position.y = 1 + window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    lbwheel.current.position.y = -1 - window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    rbwheel.current.position.y = 1 + window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    bgroup.current.position.y = -0.45 - window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    fgroup.current.position.y = -0.45 - window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    grip.current.position.y = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    btruck.current.position.z = -(window.scrollY / window.innerHeight) * 3;
    ftruck.current.position.z = -(window.scrollY / window.innerHeight) * 3;
    group.current.position.y = window.scrollY / window.innerHeight;
    group.current.rotation.y = mouseX / 2;
    group.current.rotation.x = mouseY - window.scrollY / window.innerHeight / 6;
  });

  const devScale = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;

  return (
    <group
      scale={devScale}
      ref={group}
      {...props}
      dispose={null}
      rotation={[-0.4, 0, 0]}
    >
      <mesh
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        ref={grip}
        geometry={nodes.Circle002_1.geometry}
        material={wired}
      />
      <mesh
        castShadow
        receiveShadow
        geometry={nodes.Circle002_2.geometry}
        material={materials.skateboard_wood}
      />
      <group
        ref={bgroup}
        position={[-2.11, -0.45, 0]}
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
        scale={[0.1, 0.76, 0.1]}
      >
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          ref={btruck}
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder_1.geometry}
          material={nodes.Cylinder_1.material}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder_2.geometry}
          material={nodes.Cylinder_2.material}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder001.geometry}
          material={wired}
          ref={lbwheel}
          position={[0, -1.12, 0]}
          rotation={[0, -Math.PI / 2, 0]}
          scale={[10.47, 1.31, 10.47]}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder002.geometry}
          material={wired}
          ref={rbwheel}
          position={[0, 1.12, 0]}
          rotation={[Math.PI, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
          scale={[10.47, 1.31, 10.47]}
        />
      </group>
      <group
        ref={fgroup}
        position={[2.11, -0.45, 0]}
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, Math.PI]}
        scale={[0.1, 0.76, 0.1]}
      >
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          ref={ftruck}
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder013.geometry}
          material={nodes.Cylinder013.material}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder013_1.geometry}
          material={nodes.Cylinder013_1.material}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder004.geometry}
          material={wired}
          ref={lwheel}
          position={[0, -1.12, 0]}
          rotation={[0, -Math.PI / 2, 0]}
          scale={[10.47, 1.31, 10.47]}
        />
        <mesh
          castShadow
          receiveShadow
          geometry={nodes.Cylinder005.geometry}
          material={wired}
          ref={rwheel}
          position={[0, 1.12, 0]}
          rotation={[Math.PI, Math.PI / 2, 0]}
          scale={[10.47, 1.31, 10.47]}
        />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/skateboard.gltf");
```

Answer (score 0):

the first thing i could say is to divide your file into several files.

for example you can remove your GLTFResult along with two imports that are used only in that, THREE and GLTF

and like the above you can group

also you can create a mesh folder with multiple mesh components inside and group the code of each mesh into a single mesh, like

GripMesh.jsx

with the ref and the imports inside.

Comment: if you break your code into multiple components you will not lose any performance